# <a> tag as value in <td>

Tags: php, html

I have the php code for a td as part of a table in a form:

```
"<td class=\"td_ing\">
  <input type=\"text\" name=\"ing[]\" value=\"".$row['somevalue']."\" class=\"ingr\">
</td>\n";
```

`$row['somevalue']` can somtimes be an anchor tag I wish to output in a raw form.  I.e., I want `<a href='http://www.somewhere.com`>This is a link` to display exactly as that string so it can be edited.

I tried replacing the `value=\"".$row['somevalue']."\"` with `value='".$row['somevalue']."'` but to know avail.  HTML validator did not like that.

Comment: @Quentin: This is obviously not the same question, despite being related. The answer is not even the same.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit — It is the same question, except the duplicate is one step further along. The answer is more or less identical too, `htmlentities` just converts more characters than `htmlspecialchars`.

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of escaping for such a short bit of code. Why not use:

```
$someVal = $row['someval'];
$someVal = htmlentities($someVal, ENT_QUOTES);
$html .= "<td class='td_ing'>...";
```

Remember, you can use `$someVal` inside double-quotes without escaping.